# Telegram API: how to get username from id (Python telepot)?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telepot

I save ids of all users of my bot in a database but how can I get their current username if I know id? I'm using Python 3 and Telepot framework.

Answer (score 1):

Information about a user from **user_id** can be obtained by the `getChat` method in `telepot`.

```py
bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
info = bot.getChat(user_id)
print(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the inforamtion of an account by checking the entity.

You can try to get the entity with this method:

```
entity = client.get_entity(chat_id)
```

then `Print` the entity and try to get the name from there with something like `name = entity.chat.name`